# Adding whitelist batch function

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, arrays

So for my project I want to add a function that allows me to add multiple addresses and assign a name to those addresses that will be later used for minting their NFTs. This function takes in an array of addresses and an array of strings. My idea was to iterate through both arrays using a single for loop for the logic. Bellow is what I have written so far.

```
function whitelistBatch(address[] memory rec, string[] memory name) public onlyOwner { 
  
    for(uint i =0; i< rec.length; i++){  
      count += 1;
      approved[rec[i]] = true;
      buyerName[rec[i]] = name[i];
      buyer[rec[i]] = count;
      
    }
   
 }
```

The error I received when manually entering the addresses ( format is as followed [0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4,  0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2]) on remix was `Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (argument=null value="[0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4  0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2]" code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=abi/5.5.0)`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a problem with the way you format the arguments.
Make sure to add quotes around each address (arguments in web3 have to be passed as strings). <s>Also, based on the stack trace you show, you may have a `,` missing between the addresses as well.</s>

e.g.

```
rec: ["0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4","0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2"]

name: ["a", "b"]
```